# Is it possible to automate Cypress with Microsoft Login Authentication?

Tags: azure, automation, single-sign-on, cypress, multi-factor-authentication

I'm currently attempting to automate our webpage, however before accessing our page the user is redirected to www.login.microsoftonline.com to enter a username, password and authentication token sent my SMS. Once entered successfully, the user is redirected to our webpage.

I've read multiple articles although struggling to find any help or strong code references.

E.g. of our workflow:

1. User visits www.example.com
2. User is redirected to www.login.microsoftonline.com
3. User enters username, password and authentication token
4. User is redirected to www.example.com

Currently when trying to execute the following code, cypress shows:
[login.microsoftonline.com refused to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3SPR.png)

```js
describe('Test', function() {
  it('My Test', function() {
    cy.request('POST', 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'),
    {
      auth: {
        username: 'myUsername' , 
        password: 'myPassword'
      }
    }
    cy.visit('https://example.com')
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.contains('Text I expect')
  })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: The Azure AD product team has told me that it is most likely not a good idea to create automation to login with the login page, as they might detect it as a bot and block it, causing your tests to break.

Comment: Thanks @juunas is there anyway to bypass the login at least? Or trick Cypress into thinking it's logged in.

Comment: You'd need to probably acquire the token somehow and inject it into the app. It's an interesting topic I'd like to explore in a future blog :)

Comment: Because there is the Resource Owner Password Credentials authentication flow you can use to post user credentials to AAD and get tokens. Testing delegated access is one scenario I might use this flow in. It should not be used in typical authentication scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @juunas . Do you know how the Resource Owner Password Credentials authentication flow can be accessed and passed on the token details? Appreciated

Comment: Here's the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: Try https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro tool. This tool allows you to automate sites customized on Dynamic365. Good luck.

Comment: Did you find a way to test this?

Comment: I'm also interested in it.